# VMware Fusion 3.1.1: Keys randomly stuck in XP guest while typing

Tags: macos, windows-xp, osx-snow-leopard, vmware-fusion

I'm having a strange issue where keys will randomly repeat on my WinXP guest OS within VMware Fusion as I am typing. When a character starts repeating (this could be a letter, number, space, or even backspace), it will only stop once I hit another key on the keyboard.

I do use an external USB Apple keyboard most of the time, although I've confirmed that it also happens with a non-Apple keyboard and while using the MBP keyboard itself. I've also tried decreasing the key repeat rate within the OSX Keyboard Preference with no luck.

Any other suggestions?

Info:

- 15" Unibody MBP, 4GB RAM

  Snow Leopard (10.6.4)

  VMware Fusion 3.1.1

  Guest OS: WinXP with all patches, latest VMware Tools is installed

Answer (score 1):

This is undoubtedly a bug in VMWare Fusion. I'm seeing it too.